# The treeview is not displayed in html [doxygen 1.8.17]

Tags: doxygen

I use the same configuration file in win10 and ubuntu 20.04 to generate html, but in ubuntu 20.04 the HTML treeview is not displayed in index.html.

I hope you understand me. I need the treeview to connect to other pages.

How can I solve this problem？

Thanks for all your help.

Reply to @Albert,
My Doxyfile settings as below：

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17
PROJECT_NAME           = PROJECT
PROJECT_NUMBER         = v050051
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "Test"
PROJECT_LOGO           = ./logo.png
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = .
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
INPUT                  = . \
                         ../../common/api.h
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.l \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.pyw \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f95 \
                         *.f03 \
                         *.f08 \
                         *.f18 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf \
                         *.ice
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXAMPLE_PATH           = ../../tools/test.c
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = YES
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
MATHJAX_RELPATH        =
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
GENERATE_XML           = YES
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
```

I further compared the log difference between win10 and ubuntu as follows:

[image]

Comment: Are ubuntu and Windows using the same doxygen version 1.8.17? Are both using the same doxygen settings file (`Doxyfile`), Show your differences in the `Doxyfile` compared to the default settings: `doxygen -d Doxyfille`

Comment: 1. Ubuntu and Windows using the same doxygen version 1.8.17, and Windows can display the treeview in HTML.
2. Yes, there are the same doxygen settings file.
3. doxygen 1.8.17 show differences in the Doxyfile compared to the default settings: doxygen -x Doxyfile as below...

Comment: # Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
EXTRACT_ALL        = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
INPUT                  = . \
                         ../../common/api.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXAMPLE_PATH           = ../../tools/test.c
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = YES
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
MATHJAX_RELPATH        =
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
GENERATE_XML           = YES
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES

Comment: Always place the relevant information not in the comment but in the question. Makes it better readable and understandable.

Comment: Unfortunately no idea why this happens on Ubuntu, I was thinking maybe you minimized the treeview (moving the divider to the left) and the next time this was remembered (though I could not reproduce this behavior on Windows). Another problem might be the version of the browser / some limitations in the browser handling javascript code.

Comment: Furthermore, when I setting "DISABLE_INDEX  = No" as the default setting, Ubuntu also can't display the index in HTML.

Comment: The difference between the `dot` parts might be exaplained due to the fact that in the Ubuntu version you are looking at the second run of doxygen here and on Windows at the first run. In case doxygen sees that the graphical files are present (by means of the `md5` files) it does not recreate the graphical files. This has no influence at the treeview.

Comment: After comparing the "html" folder of windows and ubuntu, it is found that the content of jquery.js of ubuntu is empty.
But I don't know why doxygen generate the empty jquery.js in ubuntu.

Comment: That is very strange (the files should be identical), I assume all other `js` files are not of size 0 (and identical on windows and Ubuntu). Are you using a precompiled version of doxygen for Ubuntu or did you compile it yourself?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. All other `js` files are not size 0 (and mostly identical on Windows and Ubuntu).
I install doxygen on Ubuntu by using `sudo apt install doxygen`

Comment: Looks all OK, strange though that I didn't see any other reports about this issue. Can you compile doxygen yourself, it is not too difficult: `git clone https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen.git` `cd doxygen` `mkdir build` `cd build` `cmake ..` `make` and in the bin directory there is the master executable. In case you want another released version you could give after `cd build` `git checkout Release_1_8_17` etc.

Comment: It's looks like the problem cause by that I 'doxygen' in the shared folders; There has no issue on 'jquery.js' when I 'doxygen' in Ubuntu local folders, and `treeview` can display normally. Thanks for your great help！！！

Comment: Does one or another virusscanner kick in on the shared folder?

Comment: How do I know if a virus scanner has kick in on the shared folder？

Comment: Is it a company dreve ? Maybe the systems group wil know about it.

Comment: No, it is private. The share folder is link to my windows OS.

Comment: That is indeed strange as I would have expected that when on one place it isn't present it also wouldn't be present on another place. Also it is strange that only one file is "hit" as the writing of files is everywhere in the same way.