# How do I make the md file only appear on the homepage [doxygen 1.8.17]

Tags: doxygen

How do I make the md file only appear on the homepage, but not on the filelist at the same time.
This problem is not appear on `doxygen 1.9.2` when using same file structure as on `doxygen 1.8.17`.
As example, I don't want `man_page.md`,`subpage_A.md`,`subpage_B.md` appear on the filelist.

```
doc---
 |---man_page.md
 |---subpage_A.md
 |---subpage_B.md
 |---api
      |---api_a.h
      |...
 |---Doxyfile
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You wrote: "This problem is not appear on `doxygen 1.9.2` when using same file structure as on `doxygen 1.8.17`." So it looks like it was a feature / bug fixed after `1.8.17`, suggest to update to `1.9.2` (when you have to build doxygen yourself for this: see my comment with your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69644487/1657886).

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I have no idea how to update to `1.9.2` after `git checkout Release_1_8_17`.

Comment: instead of `git checkout Release_1_8_17` use `git checkout Release_1_9_2`

Comment: After `git checkout Release_1_9_2`, there still get the `doxygen -version` `1.8.17`.

Comment: Did you rebuild? Are you sure you started the right executable?

Comment: After `git checkout Release_1_9_2`, I redo `cmake ..` `make`. And then `doxygen -version` is `1.8.17`

Comment: I `download doxygen-1.9.2.linux.bin.tar.gz ` `tar xf doxygen-1.9.2.linux.bin.tar.gz` `cd doxygen-1.9.2`  `mkdir build` `cd build` `cmake ..` `make` `sudo make install`. This way can workable to excute `doxygen -version` `1.9.2`.

Comment: As far as I can see: The difference between the version with the git clone and getting the tarball is that it looks like after the tarball version you do `sudo make install` and don't do this is case of the git clone. This leaves in case of the git clone version the original doxygen version in its place. When you would start doxygen with `<your_path>/build/bin/doxygen` I think you would get the doxygen version you wanted.